# Squarespace jQuery implemetation

Tags: jquery, templates, procedure, squarespace

Is there a good way to implement jQuery in a squarespace site? This is for a template based site by the way. I'd like to just do it via a simple `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>` kind of implementation, if that's possible. I'm new to squarespace's way of doing things, so maybe I'm missing something. I've been doing it via header injection and I've tried a few different urls which should have the file present, but with no success. Is this possible with squarespace and if so, how should I be going about it? 
From what I've read on the forums and since header injection should be putting the code in `<head>` tags, it seems like this should be working so I'm kind of stumped. Could this be related to Squarespace 6?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to link the jQuery script in a code block, at the top of each page that uses it.

If you need query site-wide, use the code-injection option.

Just edit the page you want to use jQuery on, and insert a 'Code' block. In that code block, paste:

This will use the jQuery script hosted on Google's CDN. It's faster than self-hosted, and easier to boot.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a link to the header.
Go to the Settings > Advanced > Code Injection and then add this link `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>` to the Header area.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with the developer functionality that they offer. 
http://developers.squarespace.com/

Squarespace also offer a solution called Code injection, which does what you want. (However i have not tried this later one.)